# how to handle null date from csv to insert db

Tags: php, mysql

Import csv file with one or more `date filed` and I'm insert into my db with this code below:

```
'" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $data[37]))) . "',
```

But when date column has no date, I mean null or blank then it insert 1969-12-31. That's why I'm trying to use case within insert statement like belw:

```
case when '".addslashes($data[37])."' is not null then '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $data[37]))) . "' else null end,
```

still result is same, Any idea would much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the check in the PHP side:

```
'".(empty($data[37]) ? "NULL" : date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $data[37]))))."',
```